# Remove duplication in python django_tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm using django_tables2, and have ended up with the following two tables which are almost identical:

```
class UserMapsetTable(Table):

    edit = ButtonColumn('Edit', 'mapsets_users_edit')
    mappings = ButtonColumn('Mappings', 'mapsets_users_mappings')

    class Meta:
        model = UserMappingRuleSet
        fields = (
            'name', 
            'notes'
        )
        attrs = responsive_table_attrs()


class ReadingMapsetTable(Table):

    edit = ButtonColumn('Edit', 'mapsets_readings_edit')
    mappings = ButtonColumn('Mappings', 'mapsets_readings_mappings')

    class Meta:
        model = ReadingMappingRuleSet
        fields = (
            'name', 
            'notes'
        )
        attrs = responsive_table_attrs()
```

How do I remove/reduce the duplication?

Comment: Both are different models. So what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Check out https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels

Comment: @ArpitSolanki These are different models but as you can see, they share similarities. I am trying to abstract the common parts, which is the basis of DRY programming. I have done so with the views and templates, but the table part is proving difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they really are this similar, you could write a factory to dynamically create the `Table` classes for you:

```
def table_factory(Model, name):
    class Table(tables.Table)

        edit = ButtonColumn('Edit', 'mapsets_' + name + '_edit')
        mappings = ButtonColumn('Mappings', 'mapsets_' + name + '_mappings')

        class Meta:
            model = Model
            fields = (
                'name', 
                'notes'
            )
            attrs = responsive_table_attrs()
    return Table

UserMapsetTable = table_factory(UserMappingRuleSet, 'users')
ReadingMapsetTable = table_factory(ReadingMapRuleSet, 'readings')
```

In this example, I would not advise doing this. You probably need changing one of the two tables later which will be a PITA.

Another way would be to have some method on the model's returning the right value for `mapset_{}_edit`. Then you could just change the implementation of your `ButtonColumn` to ask the model for the correct value.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I do this kind of all the time in js but didn't think of trying it in Python. I hear you on the warning but in this case these tables are to be treated the same.